# Why does PersistentObjectSpace sometimes return a proxy and sometimes return an object?

Tags: entity-framework, xaf

The debugger shows me that in the following code

```
  _taxRate =
                    PersistentObjectSpace.FindObject<TaxRate>(CriteriaOperator.Parse("[TaxCodeId] = ?", TaxCodeId));

                var _product2 =
                    PersistentObjectSpace.FindObject<Product>(CriteriaOperator.Parse("[ItemId] = ?", ItemId));
```

_taxRate is a poco but _product2 is a proxy

[image: poco and proxy]

The objects are

```
[Table("TaxCode")]
[DefaultProperty("TaxCode")]
[ImageName("BO_List")]
public class TaxRate : BasicBo
{
    [Key] public short TaxCodeId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RuleRequiredField(DefaultContexts.Save)]
    [StringLength(20, ErrorMessage = "The field cannot exceed 20 characters. ")]
    public string TaxCode { get; set; }
    [Required]
    [RuleRequiredField(DefaultContexts.Save)]
    public decimal Percentage { get; set; }
    

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return TaxCode;
    }
}
```

and

```
[Table("MyExtItem")]
[DefaultProperty("ProductCode")]
[NavigationItem("Config")]
public class Product : BasicBo
{
    [Key]
 
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public string ItemName { get; set; }
  
    [Column("Item Number")] public string ProductCode { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(10)] public string UnitName { get; set; }
  
    public int? ProductImageId { get; set; }
   
    [ForeignKey("ProductImageId")] public virtual ProductImage ProductImage { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ItemId")] public virtual ExtMaterialProperty ExtMaterial { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour when EF is configured to support lazy loading.

TaxRate holds no references to other entities so EF can return a concrete instance.
Product contains two references to other entities, ProductImage and ExtMaterial.

If I run the code:

```
var product = context.Products.Single(x => x.ItemId == itemId);
```

to get a product, EF uses a proxy in order to be prepared for when I try to access something like ProductImage.

```
var imageName = product.ProductImage.Name;
```

You can disable the proxies using `Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled` on the DbContext. (EF6)   This does mean that any references will need to be eager loaded or explicitly loaded, as Lazy Loading will not function without the proxies.